# How to count number of {True,True} outputs?

Tags: programming

```
Do[Print[{x + y + z == 3, x + y > z}], {x, 1, 2, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}, {z, 1, 2, 1}]
```

If I run this syntax I get a series of Outputs, I am trying to Count only the number of outputs which is `{True,True}`

Comment: `list = Table[{x + y + z == 3, x + y > z}, {x, 1, 2, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}, {z, 1, 2, 1}]; Count[list, {True, True}, Infinity]`. How about using `Count` when you want to count?

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) instead of `Do` and `Print`, then [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html) with an appropriate *levelspec*:

```
Count[
 Table[{x + y + z == 3, x + y > z}, {x, 2}, {y, 2}, {z, 2}],
 {True, True},
 {-2}
]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach:

```
test = Tuples[{1, 2}, 3];
Cases[{{##1}, #1 + #2 + #3 == 3, #1 + #2 > #3} & @@@ test, {_, True, 
  True}]
```

yielding (as one would expect):{{{1, 1, 1}, True, True}}

or you could use:

```
Pick[test, And[#1 + #2 + #3 == 3, #1 + #2 > #3] & @@@ test]
```

To count just use `Length` (obviously unnecessary in this case)

Comment: FYI a nice shorthand for `#1 + #2 + #3` is `+##`

Comment: @SimonWoods thank you Simon Woods: always learning

Comment: @Simon out of curiosity did you learn that from me or come up with it yourself?  Do you also use `1##`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think I must have learnt it from you, sorry I should have acknowledged that. I've used `1##` but only for fun.

Comment: @Simon I don't expect acknowledgement; I was just curious.  I'm the only one I can recall seeing use that around here but I know we have a similar style.  (I love it when you show me how to make *my* code more terse!)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, storing the whole list before counting may be inappropriate (perhaps the list is huge). In this case, this solution may be useful:

```
count = 0;
Do[If[And @@ {x + y + z == 3, x + y > z}, count++],
   {x, 1, 2, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}, {z, 1, 2, 1}
];
count
```

> 1

Comment: If the list is huge, then speed might be a consideration.  `And[x + y + z == 3, x + y > z]` should be faster; also compiling should save time.

Answer (score 1):

(Before Mr.W updates his post:)

```
Boole[(+##1 == 3) ~And~ (+##2 > #1)] & ~Array~ {2, 2, 2} ~Total~ -1
(* 1 *)
```

or

```
cnt = 0; (+##1 == 3)&&(+##2 > #1) & ~Array~ {2, 2, 2}//.{True :> cnt++}; cnt
```

or

```
cnt = 0; (cnt += Boole[+##1 == 3 && +##2 > #1]) & ~Array~ {2, 2, 2}; cnt
```

Comment: I edited your post to make the infix more readable, as I always recommend.  Also I don't believe `Rule` was correct so I replaced it.  +1 for syntax fun.  p.s. `##1` and `#1` can be written `##` and `#`, for those who like to save characters. p.p.s. `&&` and `:>` are already infix so there's not much point in writing out `~And~` or `~RuleDelayed~`, other than being silly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of `True` and `False` values, you can count them by changing True values to 1 (using Boole) and summing the new list, then for the number of falses invert the list and sum:

```
list = {True, True, False};
trues = Total@Boole@list;
falses = Total@Boole[Not /@ list];
```

[Alternatively] You can also use Length with Cases with the Pattern 'if value equals' the desired boolean:

```
trues = Length@Cases[list, x_ /; x == True] 
falses = Length@Cases[list, x_ /; x == False]
```