# Can't plot recursive function

Tags: plotting, recursion

I am new to *Mathematica* and now I could use some help.

Trying to plot any of these functions generates a `$RecursionLimit` exception and I am wondering why.

```
G[y_] := 0.7 G[y - 1]
G[0] = 100;

J[y_] := 0.1*G[y - 1] + 0.6 J[y - 1]

H[y_] := 0.2*J[y] + 0.8*H[y - 1]
H[0] = 0

Plot[ G[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Evaluating any of `G[2]`, `H[4]`, `J[3]` works fine.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Use `DiscretePlot[G[x], {x, 0, 10}]` . You are trying to plot for all `x` (Reals) between 0 and 10.

Comment: @belisarius You reply or Community Wiki or something? :)

Comment: The problem is that the implicit assumption is that recursion stops when the input reaches zero. This only works when the starting input in the call of `G` is a positive integer, which generally won't be the case in a Plot. You could use DiscretePlot as belisarius suggests or define the second part of the function as `G[y_/;y<=0]=100`.

Comment: @Öskå Still pondering about this question http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1244/193 :)

Comment: @belisarius so am I :D But when I answer in [comments](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47169/how-to-count-number-of-true-true-outputs#comment139947_47169) sometimes someone answers the same in a [proper answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47172/1356) :) So I did ask what was your plans :)

Comment: @Öskå Let's upvote m_goldberg's answer! :)

Comment: @belisarius Already did ;o) Looks like a good answer to me, but I'm going to add a pretty plot! :D

Answer (score 4):

Here are two reasonable answers to your question.

- [(Belisarius)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/cant-plot-recursive-function#comment140375_47318)

  > Use `DiscretePlot[G[x], {x, 0, 10}]` . You are trying to plot for all x (Reals) between 0 and 10
- [(Sjoerd C. de Vries)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/cant-plot-recursive-function#comment140385_47318)

  > The problem is that the implicit assumption is that recursion stops when the input reaches zero. This only works when the starting input in the call of G is a positive integer, which generally won't be the case in a Plot. You could add `G[y_]/;y <= 0] = 100` to the definition of `G`.

Thus, by combining each of them you have:

```
G[y_] := 0.7 G[y - 1]
G[y_] /; y <= 0 = 100
G[0] = 100;

J[y_] := 0.1*G[y - 1] + 0.6 J[y - 1]

H[y_] := 0.2*J[y] + 0.8*H[y - 1]
H[0] = 0;

Show[{DiscretePlot[G @ x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[G @ x, {x, 0, 10}]}]
```

[image]